# PostgreSQL count() works extremely slow on replication slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm using postgres replication. I have one master and 2 slaves.
I have table `first` with 1 500 000 rows. If I perform `select count(*) from first` on master, it takes less than a second, but on both slaves it takes more than 500 seconds! Sometimes it's executing forever! It's ridiculous!

Query plan on master

```
Aggregate  (cost=246018.54..246018.55 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Seq Scan on news_event  (cost=0.00..242254.63 rows=1505563 width=0)
```

On slave I can't get query plan - query execution works more than 30 minutes, I stop it.

Also, I have table `second` with 6 500 000 rows, and count for this table works equally fast on master and both slaves.

Problem appeared after adding new column to `first` table. About 24 hours before I added nullable column, and after that manually inserted default values to all rows. After that slave works extremely slow. All data on slaves is up to date.

I runned vacuum and analyze - nothing changed.

Comment: do you see disk wait or so? maybe you can post some "explain (analyze true, costs true, buffers true) SELECT ..." ...

Comment: Are you logging checkpoints (restartpoints)?  If so, what do you see in the log?  If not what happens if you shutdown and restart the slave?